# Insert Html to mail Function - PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I am doing a reset password for a site i just felt like doing, Ok So What I Am trying to insert a HTML 'A' Tag into my `$message` Variable and show it in The Email i send out to where it will be a link

For Example:

```
$to = $torecoveremail;
$subject = "You Forgot Your Password At: " . $title;
$message = "
    Your Username: " . $recoverusername . "
    Your Email: " . $recoveruseremail . "
    Your First Name: " . $recoveruserfname . "
    Your Last Name: " . $recoveruserlname . "
    Reset Password Follow This Link:
    <a href=\"yourphotomake.info/shiylohs/cms/admin432/passreset.php?id=" . $passresetid . "\">Reset Password</a> ";
mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

and the out put from the email that is sent is:

```
Your Username: ben
    Your Email: ben@tvstartup.com
    Your First Name: ben
    Your Last Name: ben
    Reset Password Follow This Link:
    <a href="yourphotomake.info/shiylohs/cms/admin432/passreset.php?id=15">Reset Password</a>
```

And what I want the email out put to be is this:

```
Your Username: ben
    Your Email: ben@tvstartup.com
    Your First Name: ben
    Your Last Name: ben
    Reset Password Follow This Link:
    Reset Password
```

Thank You A Lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specify headers.

```
$to = $torecoveremail;
$subject = "You Forgot Your Password At: " . $title;

$headers = "From: bob@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: bob@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<p>Your Username: ben</p>';
$message .= '<p>Your Email: ben@tvstartup.com</p>';
$message .= '<p>Your First Name: ben</p>';
$message .= '<p>Your Last Name: ben</p>';
$message .= '<p>Reset Password Follow This Link:</p>';
$message .= '<p><a href="yourphotomake.info/shiylohs/cms/admin432/passreset.php?id=15">Reset Password</a></p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

For more options use PHPMAILER. Its very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to include the Content-Type member in the 4th parameter.  See the following example (slightly modified from [php.net/mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)):

```
<?PHP
$message = "<HTML><BODY><B>SOME HTML</B></BODY></HTML>";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Also noted on PHP.net:

> ```
> Note:
>
> If intending to send HTML or otherwise Complex mails, it is recommended to use the PEAR package » PEAR::Mail_Mime.
> ```